# What is the best way to sort a List of objects with a start value?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

What is the best way to sort a List of object with a start value? My list has the items:

```
obj a
obj b
obj c
obj d

a.index = 1
b.index = 3
c.index = 2
d.index = 4
start value = 3;
```

sorted list must be `{b,d,a,c}`

Thanks for help.

Comment: *Why* would that be the result of sorting? And what do you mean by "with start value"? There's not nearly enough information here. You should clarify your question.

Comment: Are u sure sorted list must be right this?

Comment: Alex, yes. Jon, i edited my question.

Comment: @jimpanzer: Your edits don't answer any of the questions. You haven't given any more details of what you mean by "with a start value". Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm sorry that you did not understand me, but MarcinJuraszek already answered that for me. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @jimpanzer: You're lucky, basically - but *please* next time put more effort into describing the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` combination. It will work with `using System.Linq` at top of your file.

```
var source = new List<Item>() {
    new Item { index = 1, value = 'a' },
    new Item { index = 3, value = 'b' },
    new Item { index = 2, value = 'c' },
    new Item { index = 4, value = 'd' },
};

int startValue = 3;

var sortedList = source.OrderBy(i => i.index < startValue)
                       .ThenBy(i => i.index)
                       .ToList();

foreach (var item in sortedList)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.value, item.index));
```

`Item` class definition:

```
class Item
{
    public char value { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
}
```

Returns desired output:

```
b - 3
d - 4
a - 1
c - 2
```

Comment: Marcin, thanks. I did not know about "then by". Elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum value is known, you can do your special key function, like:

```
(item) => { return item.Index < MaxValue? MaxValue + item.Index: item.Index; }
```

and sort by it. If MaxValue is unknown, you can, well, find it.

Or you can simply sort the list, then split it by StartValue and concatenate parts in reverse order.